# How to Jump to a desired cell in excel when enter is pressed?

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a situation, where I'll start from cell E5 -> H5 -> E7 -> H7 -> E9 -> H9 and then back to E5

What is the VBA code to do this?

[[image: Cells entry flow]

Comment: If you protect the entire sheet except for those six cells, you can tab between them

Comment: Guess the user would save a Contact in the Spreadsheet! And if so, this can be just done by Unlocking these cells and protecting the Sheet. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not possible to unlock these cells alone and protect the sheet because, if i select a row below its name and details will show up in the fields above. But thanks for the idea it may be useful for other works

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I do exactly that to produce exam sheets - works magic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cybernetic.nomad comment seems like a better route to take IMO although you will have to re-order the entries to tab in the correct order.

Here is a `VBA` solution regardless that will always snap to the next cell in your flow photo when one of your flow cells is **changed**

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
    Case "E5"
        Range("H5").Select
    Case "H5"
        Range("H7").Select
    Case "H7"
        Range("H9").Select
    Case "H9"
        Range("E9").Select
    Case "E9"
        Range("E7").Select
    Case "E7"
        Range("E5").Select
End Select

End Sub
```

I always had a hard time figuring out when `.Select` was necessary after my first thorough shaming for it's use when I first started learning VBA. This would be the 2nd valid reason I've came across :0